# How to validate that reCaptcha is checked

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'am creating a contact form that should send the mail if the Google reCaptcha v2 is checked.
Now it echoes my text even if the reCaptcha is checked.

Ive tried moving around the reCaptcha snippet and tried to do a if(isset but seems not to work.

```
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $errorEmpty = false;
  $errorEmail = false;
  $errorCaptcha = false;

  if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)){
    echo "<span style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Fyll i alla fält!</span>";
    $errorEmpty = true;
  }
  if(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    echo "<span style='color: red;font-weight:bold;'>reCaptchan är inte ifylld!</span>";
    $errorCaptcha = true;
  }
   elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
     echo "<span style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Du måste skriva in en giltig e-mail adress!</span>";
     $errorEmail = true;
   }
    else{
      echo "<span style='color: green;font-weight: bold;'>Ditt meddelande skickades, vi återkommer inom max 3 arbetsdagar!</span>";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $secret = '';
      $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
      $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
      if($responseData->success){
  $to = $email;
  $subject = $subject;
  $text = "Name: $name\n From: $name\n Message: $message";
  $headers = "From: $email";
  if($errorEmpty == false && $errorEmail == false && $errorCaptcha == false){
  mail($to,$subject,$text,$headers);
  }
 }
} // ReCaptcha 2
```

I want the mail() function to activate if the reCaptcha is checked, otherwise I want to echo a text to the user.

Comment: btw: don't use `mail()`. It's sucks a lot. Use phpmailer or anything less medieval than `mail()`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Ok, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell where you're having an issue. Your current code will always `echo` some sort of message (albeit maybe you require a message to be displayed, success or failure).

If you are saying you aren't able to get `if($responseData->success){` to correctly validate the checked box, I would recommend you take a look at the response data through the use of `var_dump($responseData)` and see if *Google* is trying to tell you something (bad secret key, domain name, etc).

As an alternate approach, you may look into using *Google's* PHP reCaptcha library as an easier method to handling this situation -- my code, for instance:

```
function validateRecaptcha(?String $gRecaptchaResponse) {

    /* API source from: https://github.com/google/recaptcha */

    $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(***SECRET HERE***);

    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    return $resp->isSuccess();

}
```

---

PS: Be careful using `empty` to validate user input. If a user decided to submit a message with only `0` as the content, your `if(...|| empty($message)){` check would fail.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

i took a look at your code and found some errors. i am pasting the corrected code below, try it and let me know if it solves your problem.

```
<?php
$error = false;
$output = '';

$name    = $_POST["name"];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
  $output = "<span style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Fyll i alla fält!</span>";
  $error = true;
}
if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
  $output = "<span style='color: red;font-weight:bold;'>reCaptchan är inte ifylld!</span>";
  $error = true;
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $output =  "<span style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Du måste skriva in en giltig e-mail adress!</span>";
  $error = true;
}
if ($error) {
  echo $output;
} else {
  $secretKey = "YOUR-SECRET-KEY";
  $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' .
    urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
  $response = file_get_contents($url);
  $responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);
  if ($responseKeys["success"]) {

    // mail then
    $to = $email;
    $email_subject = $subject;
    $email_body = "Name: $name\n From: $name\n Message: $message";
    //Send the email!
    $mail_check = mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body);
    if ($mail_check) {
      echo "Mail Sent!";
    } else {
      echo 'Mail Failed';
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Response not Success';
  }
}
?>
```